# Remove one number from array of number to sort the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

We have array of numbers, we need to find the total number of ways that we can remove one number in the array if removing that, will sort the array.

For example if we have [3,4,5,4] we should return 2 because if we remove 5 or the second 4 our array will be sorted.

But if we get something like [4,5,2,3,4] we should return 0 because removing any of them will not sort the array.

I believe that this is something related to [Longest increasing subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence)

Correct me if I'm wrong, but this should work like this :

We should find the longest increasing subsequence and delete everything not in that subsequence.

With that in mind, I used some function like this to find the LIS :

```
function findSubsequence(arr){
var allSubsequence = [],
    longestSubsequence = null,
    longestSubsequenceLength = -1;

for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){          //i=1
    var subsequenceForCurrent = [arr[i]],
        current = arr[i],
        lastElementAdded = -1;
    for(var j=i;j<arr.length;j++){
        var subsequent = arr[j];
        if((subsequent > current) && (lastElementAdded<subsequent)){
            subsequenceForCurrent.push(subsequent);
            lastElementAdded = subsequent;
        }
    }
    allSubsequence.push(subsequenceForCurrent);
}
for(var i in allSubsequence){
    var subs = allSubsequence[i];
    if(subs.length>longestSubsequenceLength){
        longestSubsequenceLength = subs.length;
        longestSubsequence = subs;
    }
}
return longestSubsequence;
}


(function driver(){
    var sample = [87,88,91, 10, 22, 9,92, 94, 33, 21, 50, 41, 60, 80];
    console.log(findSubsequence(sample));
})();
```

But this give me the highest numbers, I'm not sure how should I remove one of them to keep the array sort and find all possible ways.

Any Idea?

Comment: you mean remove highest number without position change?

Comment: Why can you remove the 4, if 4 is not the highest number, but 5?

Comment: @VasimVanzara well, should return the number of ways that we can remove the highest number by deleting one of them.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I should find all the possible ways, by removing one number from the array, so one option is 5, which will give us 3,4,4 which still sorted, the other one is removing the last 4, which give us 3,4,5

Comment: With input `[3,1,4,5]` is it ok to remove the 1?

Comment: @Paul it should sort the array by deleting one of them, so it's still ok.

Comment: It sounds like for your `sample` given, the answer is 0, because it's not possible to remove one item and get a sorted array, is that right?

Comment: Yea, the sample for that function is just to find the Longest increasing subsequence

Comment: @EmadDehnavi At this time the problem description seems a bit vague , because the current question description said delete one of the highest numbers.  In `[3,1,4,5]` the 1 is the lowest number, but it is also the 4th highest number.  Of course for an array of length L any number will be one of the Lth highest numbers.  So maybe that part about highest numbers is not restrictive and does nothing, or if I misunderstand, then perhaps the description needs to be more mathematically formal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That approach seems a bit complicated. I think it would be clearer *and* less resource-heavy to use a brute force approach: for every item in the array, try removing it, and then check to see if the array is sorted afterwards. But don't use `sort` to check if it's sorted (that has `O(N log N)` complexity), instead, just check to see that every item in the array is the same or greater than the previous one (`O(N)`):

```js
const checkSorted = arr => arr.every((num, i, arr) => i === 0 || num >= arr[i - 1]);
const checkRemovalCount = arr => arr.reduce((countSoFar, _, i, arr) => {
  const removedArr = [...arr.slice(0, i), ...arr.slice(i + 1)];
  return countSoFar + checkSorted(removedArr);
}, 0);
console.log(checkRemovalCount([3,4,5,4]));
console.log(checkRemovalCount([4,5,2,3,4]));
console.log(checkRemovalCount([87,88,91, 10, 22, 9,92, 94, 33, 21, 50, 41, 60, 80]));
```

Comment: Couldn't agree with you more. This is the best approach.

Answer (score -2):

You can remove highest number using Math Library.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
var sample = [87,88,91, 10, 22, 9,92, 94, 33, 21, 50, 41, 60, 80];
sample.sort(function(a, b){return a - b});
list = remove_highest(sample)

console.log(list) // [9, 10, 21, 22, 33, 41, 50, 60, 80, 87, 88, 91, 92]

function remove_highest(list) {
    return list.filter(function(n) { return n != Math.max.apply( Math, list ) })
}       
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But it should remove the highest if only deleting it from array, make the array sorted.

Comment: after remove you can sort array.

Comment: @EmadDehnavi I have updaed my answer. output of above code will be  [9, 10, 21, 22, 33, 41, 50, 60, 80, 87, 88, 91, 92]